# Common database for a website and app

Tags: android, database, web, backend

I have an android app and a website for one same application(irrigation system-storing moisture level of soil and threshold).I need to store user inputs.Can I have a common database?Or how to achieve the storage and retrieval of user inputs?I was a novice in android app development a month ago but now I have managed to create an app.Kindly make the answers easily understandable for me.

Comment: Have a Web service on your Web server that makes your data available, along with publishing your Web site. Then, access the Web service from your Android app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaborate  more about your use case  .

in many cases If the user input is on device level , most of the mobile application will persist it on local sqlite database.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

I hope you will find it useful

Thanks